# New form while waiting receive Udp message

Tags: c#, forms, udp

There is a form have two buttons.One button(CreateGame) send broadcast message using Udpclient then listen for joining player's ip and immediately open form2,when clicked join game(button2) listen for host's ip then send message to hostIP and open form2.I want to open new form while waiting for host's ip(click join game) and when it receive ip ,close form.Is there a way to do that? This is the code.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        byte[] data = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Created.");
        UdpClient broadcaster = new UdpClient(1500);
        IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 1500);
        broadcaster.Send(data, data.Length, endPoint);

        UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(1501); 
        IPEndPoint endxPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1501);
        Byte[] receivebytes = listener.Receive(ref endxPoint);
        string clientIP = Convert.ToString(endxPoint.Address);

        broadcaster.Close();
        listener.Close();

        Form2 a = new Form2(clientIP,"host");
        a.Show();           
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {





    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UdpClient receiver = new UdpClient(1500);
        IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1500);
        Byte[] receivebytes = receiver.Receive(ref endPoint);           
        string hostIP = Convert.ToString(endPoint.Address);


        UdpClient receiverx = new UdpClient(1501);           
        IPEndPoint hostPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(hostIP), 1501);          
        byte[] data = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Connected.");
        receiverx.Send(data, data.Length, hostPoint);

        receiver.Close();
        receiverx.Close();

        Form2 a = new Form2(hostIP,"client");
        a.Show();


    }
```

Comment: You need to show the form before you try to get the connection, and then close it after you get it. In order for it to work, you'll have to remove your blocking calls though, since it will freeze the UI thread while it waits.

Comment: I don't use udp, so I may be off base, but wouldn't be easy to just set up a background worker (or similar) and have the RunWorkerCompleted or ProgressChanged (depending on your needs) methods update the forms the way you want?

Comment: @Ron Beyer i don't know how to use non-blocking receive.When i try open form before receive,form isn't shown proper.

Comment: Thats because of the blocking UI call. Google about System.Threading.Task or using the BeginReceive / EndReceive overloads on the UdpClient. Or as @JustMeToo said, use a BackgroundWorker to run the network stuff.

Comment: @JustMeToo thanks.With BackgroundWorker ,job done.